# youtube-dl Unable to download JSON metadata: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden Download from pluralsight.com

Tags: json, youtube-dl

> Unable to download JSON metadata: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

What is the problem ?

I Used last version of Youtube-dl

```
youtube-dl -u "username" -p "password" -o "c:\save_video\%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s" --all-subs --external-downloader aria2c.exe  https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/ethical-hacking-sql-injection
```

result:

```
[pluralsight:course] ethical-hacking-sql-injection: Downloading JSON metadata
[pluralsight:course] ethical-hacking-sql-injection: Downloading JSON metadata
ERROR: Unable to download JSON metadata: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden (caused by <HTTPError 403: 'Forbidden'>); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

Answer (score 0):

use vpn and add the proxy option with url ... i thing your ip has been blocked by pluralsight